# Regular expression for turning NSLogs on and off?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, regex, xcode

I've got a large Xcode project which has a few dozen NSLogs, some commented out.

The find/replace in Xcode has a regular expression option, so how could I make it comment out all active NSLogs, in a way which another find/replace can turn them back on again. So, the initial code is:

```
//NSLog(@"one");
NSLog(@"two");
```

becomes, after regex find/replace:

```
//NSLog(@"one");
//**NSLog(@"two");
```

which which turned back on becomes:

```
//NSLog(@"one");
NSLog(@"two");
```

Comment: I think you've answered your own question. To turn them on just find and replace '//**NSLog'

Comment: no, that doesn't leave the existing commented NSLogs

Comment: @cannyboy:  if you have regular expresions turned on, you need to escape the asterisks `//\*\*NSLog`

Comment: Max and JeremyP, I don't think you understand. Existing commented-out NSLogs should not change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a much better solution. Just put this in your prefix.pch file:

```
//disable logging when not in debug
#ifndef DEBUG
#undef NSLog
#define NSLog(args, ...)
#endif
```

That will disable NSLogs when your app is not in debug mode. That way you don't have to actually remove them from the code, but they'll have no performance impact.

In case you're wondering how it works, it redefines the NSLog() function as blank when the DEBUG macro is not defined. By default DEBUG is defined only for debug projects. You can change it to be toggled on and off in a different way if you prefer by just replacing the first line with #if SOME_OTHER_CONDITION.

Comment: +1 @nick no doubt it's a great solution but don't you think `NSLog` is a function instead of macro

Comment: This isn't a theoretical solution - I use it regularly. You may be right that NSLog is a function, but undefining it and redefining as a macro works fine.

Comment: I think slightly better would be `#define NSLog(...) (void)0`. This prevents compiler warnings and keeps your code a little more sane - `(void)0` is closer to an actual statement than nothingness.

Comment: @NickLockwood Yeah i told you that your code works fine that's why i have upvoted it, but i have confusion about nslog as macro

Comment: I've updated my answer to clarify that it's a function, not a macro.

Comment: Since NSLog returns void anyway, you shouldn't get any warning for using this macro as-is (I don't). It simply removes the statement (actually, technically it leaves a hanging ; which you could add to the macro definition if you're worried about it).

Comment: @NickLockwood can you make that macro too that can remove hanging `;` and one more thing is there a way to see the preprocessed file in objective-c

Comment: You can just include it in the #define NSLog(args, ...); so that the ; is part of the macro, but it really doesn't make any difference to the compiler. I'm sure there is a way to see the post-processed file (with the macros applied) but I'm not sure what it is - try Google.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution for this would be to use a macro such as DLog which you could control using a debug (or your own compiler flag). Check this [link](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/debugging/the-evolution-of-a-replacement-for-nslog)  or [this](http://cocoamatic.blogspot.com/2010/08/better-nslog-implementation.html)